# Merging dataframes with hierarchcial index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

### Question

- How to merge two dataframes, using hierarchical index?
- The index of my dataframes are `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time`

### Code example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

BTC_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[datetime.time(19,15,0),1.05,'BTC'],[datetime.time(9,20,0),1.2,'BTC']]),
                      columns = ['time','return','coin'],
                      index = [[datetime.date(2020,5,1), datetime.date(2020,5,2)]])

ETH_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[datetime.time(8,30,0),1.1,'ETH'],[datetime.time(17,30,0),0.9,'ETH']]),
                      columns = ['time','return','coin'],
                      index = [[datetime.date(2020,5,1), datetime.date(2020,5,2)]])

BTC_df 
>>>               time    return   coin
   2020-05-01   19:15:00    1.05    BTC
   2020-05-02   09:20:00    1.2     BTC

ETH_df 
>>>                time    return   coin
   2020-05-01   08:30:00    1.1     ETH
   2020-05-02   17:30:00    0.9     ETH
```

My desired output is as follows, using hierarchical index (MultiIndex)

```
merged_df
>>>               time    return   coin
   2020-05-01   08:30:00    1.1     ETH
                19:15:00    1.05    BTC
   2020-05-02   09:20:00    1.2     BTC
                17:30:00    0.9     ETH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set_index` with `append` to make `time` :

```
pd.concat([BTC_df,ETH_df]).set_index('time',append=True).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                    return coin
           time                
2020-05-01 08:30:00    1.1  ETH
           19:15:00   1.05  BTC
2020-05-02 09:20:00    1.2  BTC
           17:30:00    0.9  ETH
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sort them using [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

```
df = pd.concat([BTC_df,ETH_df])
df.rename_axis('Date').sort_values(by=['Date','time'])

                time return coin
Date
2020-05-01  08:30:00    1.1  ETH
2020-05-01  19:15:00   1.05  BTC
2020-05-02  09:20:00    1.2  BTC
2020-05-02  17:30:00    0.9  ETH
```

Comment: Can we do multi-level indexing here to get rid of repeated dates? For example, I would like to see only one `2020-05-01` instead of seeing it two times.

Comment: @Eiffelbear But for that you have make `'time'` as index too. Then you would get `MultiIndex`. See Quang's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([BTC_df,ETH_df]).sort_values(by='time', ascending=True)
```

[image]